# Reasoning about dependent and independent quantities by "degrees of freedom"

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, measure-theory

In his classic textbook [Foundations of the Theory of Probability](http://www.york.ac.uk/depts/maths/histstat/kolmogorov_foundations.pdf) Kolmogorov defines Independence a little bit differenent then it is usually done today. He denotes a probability space by $(E, \mathcal F, P)$, on page 9 he wrote:

> Given $n$ experiments $\mathcal U^{(1)}, \mathcal U^{(2)}, \mathcal U^{(n)}$, that is $n$ decompositions 
>   $$
>  E = A_1^{(i)} + A_2^{(i)} + \ldots + A_{r_i}^{(i)} \quad i = 1,2,\ldots, n
> $$
>   of the basic set $E$. It is then possible to assign $r = r_1 r_2\cdots r_n$ probabilities [...]
>
> *Definition*: $n$ experiments $\mathcal U^{(1)}, \mathcal U^{(2)}, \mathcal U^{(n)}$ are called *mutually independent*, if for any $q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_n$ the following equation holds true:
>   $$
>  P(A_{q_1}^{(1)} A_{q_2}^{(2)} \ldots A_{q_n}^{(n)}) = P(A_{q_1}^{(1)}) P(A_{q_2}^{(2)}) \ldots P(A_{q_n}^{(n)}).
> $$
>   Among the $r$ equations, there are only $r - r_1 - r_2 - \ldots - r_n + (n-1)$ indepdent equations.

In a footnote he explains:

> Actually, in the case of independence, one may choose arbitrarily only $r_1 + r_2 + \ldots + r_n$ probabilities $p_q^{(k)} = P(A_q^{(k)})$ so as to comply with the $n$ conditions
>   $$
>  \sum_q p_q^{(i)} = 1.
> $$
>   Therefore, in the general case, we have $r-1$ degrees of freedom, but in the case of independence only $r_1 + r_2 + \ldots + r_n - n$.

So my question, how this seeminly simple argument in the footnote works? When I have $n$ equations, dependent on $m \le n$ parameters, where these parameters underlie $k \le m$ degrees of freedom, why does it follows that $n - k$ equations are independent? Or more abstractly, if I have $n$ equations 
\begin{align*}
 y_1 & = \mbox{ equation on } x_1, \ldots, x_m \\
 y_2 & = \mbox{ equation on } x_1, \ldots, x_m \\
 \vdots \\
 y_n & = \mbox{ equation on } x_1, \ldots, x_m
\end{align*}
Then if I know that the $x_i$ have $k \le m$ degrees of freedom, why does I know instantly that just $n - k$ equations are indepdent, i.e. the other ones follow from the independent ones?

For the statement in Kolmogorov's book I have another explanations. If I have
$n$ experiments $\mathcal U^{(1)}, \mathcal U^{(2)}, \mathcal U^{(n)}$ then by additivity I have for each single event $A_q^{(i)}$ the linear equation
$$
 P(A_q^{(i)}) = \sum_{ \begin{subarray}{l} 1 \le q_1 \le r_1, \\ \vdots  \\ 1 \le q_{i-1} \le r_{i-1}, \\ 1 \le q_{i+1} \le r_{i+1}, \\ \vdots \\ 1 \le q_n \le r_n \end{subarray}}
 P(A_{q_1}^{(1)} \ldots A_{q_{i-1}}^{(i-1)} A_q^{(i)} A_{q_{i+1}}^{(i+1)} \ldots A_{q_n}^{(n)})
$$
i.e. summing over all other sets except the one I am looking at. This gives me $r_1 + r_2 + \ldots r_n$ linear equations. Fix some event $A_{q_i}^{(i)}$ from each experiment $\mathcal U^{(i)}$, $i = 1,\ldots, n$, then by using that the events in each individual experiment have to sum to one, and that the sum of all $r$ combinations have to sum to one I can replace the equation
$$
  P(A_q^{(i)}) = \sum_{ \begin{subarray}{l} 1 \le q_1 \le r_1, \\ \vdots  \\ 1 \le q_{i-1} \le r_{i-1}, \\ 1 \le q_{i+1} \le r_{i+1}, \\ \vdots \\ 1 \le q_n \le r_n \end{subarray}}
 P(A_{q_1}^{(1)} \ldots A_{q_{i-1}}^{(i-1)} A_q^{(i)} A_{q_{i+1}}^{(i+1)} \ldots A_{q_n}^{(n)})
$$
by
$$
 1 - \sum_{s \ne q} P(A_s^{(i)}) = 
  1 - \sum_{\substack{q_1,\ldots, q_n \\ q_i \ne q}} P(A_{q_1}^{(1)} A_{q_2}^{(2)} \ldots A_{q_n}^{(n)})
$$
and substracting one I see that this equation is linear dependent on the other, i.e. by adding all the other for the experiment $\mathcal U^{(i)}$ it could be eliminated. Therefore in the end I have $r_1 + r_2 + \ldots r_n$ linear equations, from which $n$ could be eliminated (one of each $r_i$'s equations). The linear equations have $r$ variables (the compound probabilities), which have to fulfill the additional requiremtn that they sum to one, so $r-1$ of them are independent. So I am left with
$$
 (r-1) - (r_1 + r_2 + \ldots + r_n - n)
$$
parameters, i.e. variables that could be choosen freely, and where the others depend on. Cause I have used everything these no more could be choosen freely.

A little example, if I denote the probability space by $(\Sigma, \mathcal F, P)$ and have two experiment (i.e. disjoint decompositions) 
$$
 \Sigma = A + B + C = D + E + F.
$$
I get the equations
\begin{align*}
 P(A) & = P(AD) + P(AE) + P(AF) \\
 P(B) & = P(BD) + P(BE) + P(BF) \\
 P(C) & = P(CD) + P(CE) + P(CF) \\
 P(D) & = P(AD) + P(BD) + P(CD) \\
 P(E) & = P(AE) + P(BE) + P(CE) \\
 P(F) & = P(AF) + P(BF) + P(CF)
\end{align*}
from which I get
\begin{align*}
 P(A) & = P(AD) + P(AE) + P(AF) \\
 P(B) & = P(BD) + P(BE) + P(BF) \\
 1 - P(A) - P(B) & = 1 - ( P(AD) + P(AE) + P(AF) + P(BD) + P(BE) + P(BF) ) \\
 P(D) & = P(AD) + P(BD) + P(CD) \\
 P(E) & = P(AE) + P(BE) + P(CE) \\
 1 - P(D) - P(E) & = 1 - ( P(AD) + P(BD) + P(CD) + P(AE) + P(BE) + P(CE) )
\end{align*}
together with 
$$
1 = P(AD) + P(AE) + P(AF) + P(BD) + P(BE) + P(BF) + P(CD) + P(CE) + P(CF)
$$
the following $5$ independent equations are left:
\begin{align*}
 P(A) & = P(AD) + P(AE) + P(AF) \\
 P(B) & = P(BD) + P(BE) + P(BF) \\
 P(D) & = P(AD) + P(BD) + P(CD) \\
 P(E) & = P(AE) + P(BE) + P(CE) \\
 1    & = P(AD) + P(AE) + P(AF) \\
      & = P(BD) + P(BE) + P(BF) \\
      & = P(AD) + P(BD) + P(CD) 
\end{align*}
Therefore from the $9$ "variables" $P(AD), P(AE), \ldots$ I could choose $9 - 5 = 4$ freely, i.e. are independent.